# Can a useQuery hook skip itself?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Instead of skipping a query by passing `skipToken` to its `useQuery` hook, is is possible for the query to skip itself?

In the RTK Query API Reference section [Setting default headers on requests](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#setting-default-headers-on-requests), there is an example where `prepareHeaders` checks the store for an auth token, and if it is there then it sets it as the Authorisation header for the request. This is exactly what I am doing in my app.

But if the token is *not* in the store then the request would fail with HTTP 403. Even worse, that failure is cached by RTKQ so the `useQuery` hook will fail again next time, even if the auth token has become available in the meantime.

So in that case I want to query to be skipped. I can only see 2 ways to do this, and neither is satisfactory:

- One way would be for the React component to check the store and pass
  `skipToken` if the auth token is not in the store. But this is a pain
  because I have to remember to do this same check in every component
  that uses the query. And I think the auth mechanism should be internal to the query code.
- Another possibility is to override `queryFn`, do the check in there,
  and return an error if the auth token isn't present. This is a bit
  clunky, and it still leaves the same problem as before: the failure
  is cached, so the `useQuery` hook will keep returning an error even
  what the auth token becomes available.

I would like a way for the query to be able to be able to skip itself if the auth token is not present (as if `skipToken` has been passed into the `useQuery` hook). Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such mechanic of skipping itself.

I'd suggest adding an `authenticated` tag to all your queries that need authentication and just invalidating that tag from your `login` mutation.

Comment: Yes, that approach is described in the [RTKQ  docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching#providing-errors-to-the-cache). In my case, the login part is done using redux-oidc, not through RTKQ, so there is no login mutation. Instead I would have to create a mutation that just invalidates the `authenticated` tag and initiate that from the login callback. I might give that a try.

Comment: You can also `dispatch(api.utils.invalidateTags('authenticated'))`

Comment: That's much better! Thank you. `<facepalm>`I thought I had seen that function before but it didn't show up in the docs when I searched. It turned out I was looking at the [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/api/api-reference), not the very similar-looking [Redux Toolkit docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#invalidatetags) `</facepalm>`